# How to Justify text in HTML?(Netsuite AdvancedPDF)

Tags: html, css, pdf, netsuite, suitescript

I m creating an Advanced PDF in ARABIC. its a kind of letter with only Arabic text. It is not getting justify. i tried using `style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;"` in `<td>` as well as in `<span>` but still no use.

Can anyone give me an idea if it is possible to justify arabic or not?
My script chunk:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<!-- <pdf dir="rtl" lang="ar"> -->
<pdf>

  <head>
    <!-- arabic Font -->
    <link name="majalla" type="font" subtype="opentype"
      src="https://5486702.app.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=8627&amp;c=5486702&amp;h=3e47c429eda24f454f39&amp;_xt=.ttf"
      bytes="6" />
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: majalla;
        font-size: 18pt;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body font-famly="ariel" header="nlheader" header-height="14%" footer="nlfooter" footer-height="20pt"
    padding="0.5in 0.7in 0.5in 0.7in" size="Letter">
    <table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
      <tr margin-top="10px">
        <td align="right" lang="Ar">
          <#if record.custbody7?has_content>
            <p align="right"><span align="right" style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;">${record.custbody7}</span>
              <#else>
                <p align="right" style="text-indent: 35px;"><span align="right">أفيدكم بأنه لا مانع لدينا من قيامكم
                    بتنفيذ المشروع أعلاه وذلك لمدة </span>
                  <span align="right" style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;">(
                    ${record.custbody_duration?string?replace('0','٠')?replace('1','١')?replace('2','٢')?replace('3','٣')?replace('4','٤')?replace('5','٥')?replace('6','٦')?replace('7','٧')?replace('8','٨')?replace('9','٩')}
                    )</span> <!-- duration -->
                  <span align="right" style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;"> تبدأ من تاريخ </span>
                  <span align="right" style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;">${record.custbody_start_date?string?replace('0','٠')?replace('1','١')?replace('2','٢')?replace('3','٣')?replace('4','٤')?replace('5','٥')?replace('6','٦')?replace('7','٧')?replace('8','٨')?replace('9','٩')}
                    م ، </span> <!-- start date -->
          </#if>
          <span align="right" style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;">ومن ثم ترفع المطالبات للإدارة المالية بتقديم جميع المستندات المؤيدة للصرف علًما بأن أصل
            هذا التعميد لدى الإدارة المالية في مكتب برنامج خدمة ضيوف الرحمن. </span>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</pdf>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At serveral places you are using `<span align="right">`. There are three problems here:

1.) `span` is an inline element – it's useless to use text-alignment in an inline element. Use `div` instead of `span`. That's a block element, and its default width is the full width of its parent element, so text alignment will have an effect.

2.) `align="right"` is not a valid HTML attribute. If you want to add the alignment to an element like a `div` directly, you have to use `<div style="text-align: right;">`. Or (better) you apply a class to the DIV and set up a CSS rule for that class which contains the desired text-alignment. If you want your text justified, use `<div style="text-align: justify;">` instead.

3.) For languages which are written from right to left, you not only use right alignment, but also add a text direction parameter like `direction: rtl;` ("right to left"), so alltogether that would be `<div style="text-align: justify; direction: rtl;">`, or (better) a CSS rule for a class containing those settings which you apply to your HTML tags.

Comment: Thank You for helping. I tried using <div> instead of <table> but it is not printing anything and showing the page as empty. Probably <div> doesnt work in the PDFs of Netsuite.